# Problem with ''mdframed" : equations not aligned with text

Tags: mdframed

Hi I want to produce this equations environment with `mdframed`

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=brown!10,linewidth=0pt]
\begin{equation}
 A_x=A \cos \theta 
\end{equation}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=brown!10,linewidth=0pt]
\begin{equation}
A_y=A \sin \theta
\end{equation}
\end{mdframed}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

My problem is that I get equations not aligned with the text and the box is very long,

[image]

Please, how to align equations with the text and reduce the length of the box as in the example?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{empheq}
\definecolor{lb}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}


\newcommand*\brownlqbox[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.2em}%  
\colorbox{lb}{\hspace{.5em}#1\hspace{.5em}}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{empheq}[box=\brownlqbox]{align}
A_x &=A \cos \theta
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have anwered yourself. Very nice. +1.

Comment: Thank you Sebastiano.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I will remove the `mdframed` package and I will use `empheq` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{empheq}
\definecolor{lb}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}
\newcommand*\brownlqbox[1]{%
\colorbox{lb}{\hspace{.5em}#1\hspace{.5em}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{empheq}[box=\brownlqbox]{align}
A_x &=A \cos \theta
\end{empheq}

\begin{equation}
A_y=A \sin \theta
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sebastiano thank you for the code. Please, I want to increase the height of the equation box a little more. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You can change the value of `\fboxsep` (default is 3pt) in the definition of `\brownlqbox`.

Comment: Very kind Bernard, please, can you edit my answer because I have not understood your request in the last comment.